# Move focus to a button on a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a worksheet with form control buttons. At the end of a macro called by one button I would like to set the focus to another button, so that if I see that the first button did the job, I could just hit Enter.

I searched the site and got this

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("CommandButton1").Select
```

This selects the shape but Enter does not run it.

Methods of CommandButton do not work.

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("CommandButton1").SetFocus
```

returns the "method not supported" error.

I got this other answer:

```
Me.CommandButton1.SetFocus
```

I get "Object needed" error.

This leads me to believe that either CommandButton# object does not exist in Excel VBA or that it refers to a form but my buttons are placed directly on the spreadsheet.

Tried

```
ActiveSheet.CommandButton1.SetFocus
ActiveSheet.Buttons("Button 1").SetFocus
```

I found an old sample code with something like this:

```
CommandButton2.Caption = "CONTINUE"
CommandButton1.Enabled = False
CommandButton3.Enabled = False
```

This works in that sample, but in that sample the buttons behave differently. I suspect they are ActiveX or something else instead of form control buttons. In that sample right-clicking on them does not bring up the context menu.

I tried

```
ActiveSheet.Buttons("Button 1").ControlFormat
```

But do not know what to use next. SetFocus does not work.

Comment: I know you have mentioned it in your post but can you reconfirm it they are form control or activex control?

Comment: If it is a form control then you cannot press enter on it. Only if it is an ActiveX control, can you do that.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I wanted to use it on a form control button. ActiveX control buttons require enabling ActiveX which I wanted to avoid, but if that is the only solution, I can live with that.
Is there any other way to control a form control button with the keyboard?

Comment: Til the time you are not using `Application.Caller` in your code, you could assign a shortcut key to your macro. You can use the shortcut key to invoke the macro directly which would be the same as clicking that button ;)

Comment: @Siddharth Rout. Thank you very much for the answers. The situation is now clear to me. I am not sure which solution I will use, either changing the buttons to ActiveX or assigning a key to the macro. But now it is clear I cannot achieve my goal with a form button. 
This is very helpful, because it took me a lot of time to *not* figure it out, as the requirement to be an ActiveX control was nowhere specified.

Answer (score 2):

With an ActiveX control button named "CommandButton1", you can call

```
Me.CommandButton1.Activate
```

from the same worksheet.

Comment: The OP specifically said that he/she is looking for a solution for form controls **not** ActiveX controls.

Answer (score 0):

On a form control button named "CommandButton1", you can call

```
UserForm1.CommandButton1.SetFocus
```

This will make sure the **focus** is on the CommandButton1.